# rails form select helper not respecting "selected"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, helper

I am attempting to use the rails form `select` helper to set a selected option. The select renders a form correctly, but the `selected` property isn't being respected. Here's what I've tried:

```
  <%= form.select :time_of_day, options_for_select({
    "AM" => "1",
    "PM" => "2"}), "2" %>
```

This doesn't work. I've tried:

```
  <%= form.select :time_of_day, options_for_select({
    "AM" => "1",
    "PM" => "2"}), {selected: "2"} %>
```

This didn't work either. I though that I may be confused, so I also tried:

```
  <%= form.select :time_of_day, options_for_select({
    "AM" => "1",
    "PM" => "2"}), {selected:  "PM"} %>
```

But this didn't work either. I must be doing something wrong at a more fundamental level. How can I get the selected state to work?

Answer (score 1):

When using with `options_for_select`, the syntax will change slightly. The following should work.

```
<%= form.select :time_of_day, options_for_select( {"AM" => "1", "PM" => "2"}, "2") %>
```

The generated ***HTML*** options  would be like this

```
<option value="1">AM</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">PM</option>
```

For more Info, see [***options_for_select***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Answer (score 0):

Lets declare a variable:

```
time_day = {
    "AM" => "1",
    "PM" => "2"}
```

Now in the form,

```
<%= form.select :time_of_day, options_for_select(time_day.each_pair{|key,val| [key, val]}, :selected => "PM")  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this forms:

```
<%= form.select "time_of_day", [['AM',1], ['PM', 2]], { selected: 2 }  %>
# or
<%= form.select "time_of_day", {'AM' => 1, 'PM' => 2}, { selected: 2 }  %>
```

But I would recommend simply:

```
<%= form.select "time_of_day", ['AM','PM'], { selected: 'AM' }  %>
```

You can find more info on `select` helper from here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html